# Shortening a Python program

Tags: python

I have 22 FITS files that have the same field/column names. I load them using pyfits like for example:

```
hdulist1 = pyfits.open('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test/roncarelli_dist_halo1.fits')
hdulist2 = pyfits.open('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test/roncarelli_dist_halo2.fits')
```

then I load the table data for the 22 files likewise

```
tbdata1 = hdulist1[1].data
tbdata2 = hdulist2[1].data
```

Since all the field names are the same I say

```
fields = ['ra','dec','zcosmo','r200','m200','is_central','r']
```

and assign variables from 1 to 22 (var1, var2 etc) to the fields like:

```
var1 = dict((f, tbdata1.field(f)) for f in fields)
var2 = dict((f, tbdata2.field(f)) for f in fields)
```

Now I use np.histogram to find some values for the 22 files likewise:

```
N_1, r_hist_1 = np.histogram(var1['r'], bins=20, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
N_2, r_hist_2 = np.histogram(var2['r'], bins=20, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
```

Now I find out using the formula the value for variables I name sigma_num_1, sigma_num_2 for the different files likewise:

```
dist_1 = r_hist_1[1]
area_1 = [math.pi*(R**2-r**2) for R, r in zip(dist_1[1:], dist_1)]
sigma_num_1 = N_1/area_1
```

The code is working fine and gives me the results for sigma_num_1, sigma_num_2 etc..

**I don't want to write the above three lines for each of the 22 files to find say sigma_num_3 to sigma_num_22. 
Is there a way to do it. After finding all the 22 values of sigma, I need to find the mean of all these 22 values.**

Comment: Consider creating a _list_ of input files.

Comment: Do you know what functions are?

Comment: @BlackBear yes. But I don't know how to use functions to shorten this

Comment: @devnull could you pls elucidate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to give a variable name to every single value. You can use a [data structure](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to store all of your values while giving you a convenient way to reference each value. The trick is to abstract the parts that change between different occurrences of the same kind of variable, e.g., what's different between `hdulist1` and `hdulist2`.

For instance, you can create your `hdulist`s by putting them into a list, and forming each `open` statement by using the `format` method of strings:

```
hdulists = []
for n in range(1, 23):   # range is exclusive so you get 1-22
    hdulists.append(
        pyfits.open(
            ('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test'
            '/roncarelli_dist_halo{0}.fits').format(n)
        )
     )
```

This could also be done in a list comprehension:

```
hdulists = [pyfits.open(
                ('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test'
                '/roncarelli_dist_halo{0}.fits').format(n)
            ) for n in range(1, 23)]
```

Now, the only thing you'll need to keep in mind is that python lists start from index 0, so you will refer to what used to be `hdulist1` as `hdulists[0]`, and so on.

But you could just get smarter and do all of these steps at once inside of a function which will return the results you want. Then run that function for each of your `.fits` files.

```
def sigma_num(n):
    fields = ['ra','dec','zcosmo','r200','m200','is_central','r']
    hdulist = pyfits.open(
                  ('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test'
                  '/roncarelli_dist_halo{0}.fits').format(n)
              )
    var = dict((f, hdulist[1].data.field(f)) for f in fields)
    N, r_hist = np.histogram(var['r'], bins=20, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
    area = [math.pi*(R**2-r**2) for R, r in zip(r_hist[1:], r_hist)]
    return N/area
```

And now you can just call `sigma_num(3)` and `sigma_num(22)` to get what you used to call `sigma_num_3` and `sigma_num_22`.

To find the average, you can use the technique I set out before for iterating over a range:

```
sigma_nums = []
for n in range(1, 23):
    sigma_nums.append(sigma_num(n))
avg_sigma_num = sum(sigma_nums)/len(sigma_nums)
```

`sum` and `len` are [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). You can also abstract the above into a list comprehension, or even better, a function.

**Edit**: since you asked to have the `tbdata`s available separately, separate that part of the function into a *helper* function. The `sigma_num` can call the helper function:

```
def tbdata(n):
    """ helper function """
    hdulist = pyfits.open(
                  ('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test'
                  '/roncarelli_dist_halo{0}.fits').format(n)
              )
    return hdulist[1].data

def sigma_num(n):
    fields = ['ra','dec','zcosmo','r200','m200','is_central','r']
    tbdata = tbdata(n)
    var = dict((f, tbdata.field(f)) for f in fields)
    N, r_hist = np.histogram(var['r'], bins=20, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
    area = [math.pi*(R**2-r**2) for R, r in zip(r_hist[1:], r_hist)]
    return N/area
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But to see my 'ra', 'dec' seperately for each file, I used to say var1['ra'] which would give it. But now how should I see it?

Comment: @srivatsan What do you mean? Why should you care? It's an intermediate step in your computation of the `sigma_num`s.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I could see my table column values for each file as I could before.

Comment: @srivatsan What do you mean by "see"? Are you trying to print these values or save them to a file?

Comment: I will be using them in the near future for more calculations apart from this. That is why I wanted to know how I can access them.

Comment: Sure. Separate the function into two parts. Let me edit to show you how.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47867/discussion-between-srivatsan-and-2rs2ts)

Comment: Thank you once again!! I am new to python and this has shortened my code by many lines!!

Answer (score 1):

Use lists and loops.

```
hdulist = []
fits_path= '/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test/roncarelli_dist_halo%i.fits'
for number in range(1,23):
    hdulist.append(pyfits.open(fits_path % number)
tbdata = [hdu[1].data for hdu in hdulist]
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Basically for each file you want to compute 'sigma'. So you can create a function that takes file as parameter and returns you the 'sigma'.

You could store all files in a list and call this function when looping over the list. You could store the 'sigmas' in another list. Something like:

```
>>> def sigma(file):
...     pass
... 
>>> files = ["a", "b"]
>>> sigmas = []
>>> for f in files:
...     sigmas.append(sigma(f)
... 
>>> sigmas
[None, None]
```

Comment: OP said he knows what a function is, so obviously his problem is seeing how to use them to abstract his algorithm. This is useless.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a function to process a single file and compute its sigma

```
def find_sigma(n):
    fields = ['ra','dec','zcosmo','r200','m200','is_central','r']
    hdulist = pyfits.open('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test/roncarelli_dist_halo%d.fits' % n)
    tbdata = hdulist[1].data
    var = dict((f, tbdata.field(f)) for f in fields)
    N, r_hist = np.histogram(var['r'], bins=20, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
    dist = r_hist[1]
    area = [math.pi*(R**2-r**2) for R, r in zip(dist[1:], dist)]
    sigma_num = N/area

    return sigma_num
```

Then simply use list comprehension to find the average value:

```
average_sigma = sum([find_sigma(i) for i in range(1, 23)]) / 23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested dictionary, assign it 22 keys, and store each of your data points as sub dictionaries in the main dictionary.

e.g.

```
main_data = {}
for i in range(0,22):
  main_data['hdulist_{0}'.format(i)] = pyfits.open('/home/ssridhar/mock_test_files/Roncarelli_test/roncarelli_dist_halo{0}.fits'.format(i))
```

Comment: could you elucidate more?

Comment: If all keys are simply named `somestring_[n]` where `[n]` is a counter, it does not make any sense to put the data in a dict - you can just use a list.

Comment: @DhruvPathak Now how should I access the files seperately using main_data??

Comment: @srivatsan `main_data['hdulist_1']` etc.